# Encrypted Media Extensions encryption

Tags: html, encryption, browser, media

I understand the overview of EME but I can't seem to wrap my head on how that protect contents.  Since the browser retrieve a key from the licensing server, what is stopping an authorized user from using that key to decrypt the content and redistribute the content to non-authorized user?

Could this be that HTTPS is slow that's why EME is introduce?  Because EME can decrpyt a encrpyted video or video with only the key frames.

Comment: Congratulations, you've just discovered the fatal flaw inherent in all DRM systems - in order to play the content, the data has to be decrypted somewhere in the system, and hence it is essentially always possible to take the decrypted data at that point and use it to produce an "unauthorized" DRM-free copy. In practice of course, the DRM server providing the decryption key will usually have a means to ensure that the player requesting the key is "authorized" in some way (generally such authorization requires that the software/hardware can't be used to easily produce such copies).

Comment: I'm talking about Browsers or specifically Chrome.

Comment: is a browser like Chrome protecting the key once it's retrieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content Decryption Modules is included in the browser to handle key session.